# How to send files from azure blob storage through email?

Tags: nestjs, azure-blob-storage, nodemailer

Need to send the email with the file attachments using nest.js nodemailer.

The files are in the Azure blob storage.

Below is the code:

```
this.emailService.sendEmail({
  to: 'example@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Health Reports',
  template: 'health-forms',
  attachments: [
    {
      name: 'HealthForm.pdf',
      path: 'xxxxxxxxxx'   // need to add files in azure blob storage
    }
  ]
});
```

How to attach the files stored in azure blob storage?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I uploaded a folder with 2 files as blobs to my storage account container at the Azure portal as below,

[image]

***I tried below nextjs code to upload blob files to email with nodemailer and got the files uploaded successfully to my email.***

Before going to run the code you need to set up the email **2-Step Verification ON**, you can follow the below steps,

Go to **Manage your Google account> Security> 2-Step Verification** and turn it **ON**.

[image]

Then, search for **app passwords** and set up it as shown  below,

[image]

Select the **Mail** and **Windows Computer** then click on **GENERATE**.

[image]

This will generate a password, you should use this password in the **send-email.js** code, click on **Done**.

[image]

**Code:**

***components/EmailForm.js :***

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function EmailForm() {
  const [toEmail, setToEmail] = useState('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setToEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubjectChange = (e) => {
    setSubject(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/send-email', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ to: toEmail, subject }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Email sent successfully');
      } else {
        console.error('Failed to send email');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to send email:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        To:
        <input type="email" value={toEmail} onChange={handleEmailChange} />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Subject:
        <input type="text" value={subject} onChange={handleSubjectChange} />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Send Email</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

***pages/api/send-email.js :***

you need to use the **app password** at the **pass** in the below code,

```js
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { to, subject } = req.body;

  const connectionString = '<connec-string>';
  const containerName = '<container-name>';
  const folderPath = '<path/to/folder>'; 

  try {
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    const attachments = await getAttachmentsFromFolder(containerClient, folderPath);

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: '<Email@gmail.com>',
        pass: '<password>',
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: '<Email@gmail.com>',
      to,
      subject,
      attachments,
    };

    const result = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('Email sent successfully:', result);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Email sent successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to send email:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send email' });
  }
}

async function getAttachmentsFromFolder(containerClient, folderPath) {
  const attachments = [];
  const files = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);

  for (const file of files) {
    const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);

    const blobName = path.basename(file);
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    await blobClient.upload(fs.readFileSync(filePath), fs.statSync(filePath).size);

    attachments.push({
      filename: blobName,
      content: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
    });
  }

  return attachments;
}
```

***pages/index.js :***

```js
import EmailForm from '../components/EmailForm';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Send Email</h1>
      <EmailForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

***package.json :***

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.14.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "next": "13.4.9",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above **URL**, I send the blob files to email as below,

[image]

***The blob files were sent to email successfully as below,***

[image]

***I got the blob files in my email as below,***

[image]